# Lazy boolean evaluation in Python when using Map-Reduce

Tags: python, lazy-evaluation, reduce

I will use my example: I want to create a list of primes using the sieve of Eratosthenes. 
For each number, I check if it is composite, and if not, I append it to the list.

- Using "standard" programming:

  ```
  primes = [2]
  start = time.time()
  for i in xrange(3,primeRange,2):
      isPrime = True
      for p in primes:
          if(i % p == 0):
              isPrime = False
              break;
      if(isPrime):        
          primes.append(i)
  print "Using C++-style: ", time.time() - start, " seconds"
  ```
- Using `reduce` function:

  ```
  start = time.time()
  for i in xrange(3,primeRange,2):
      if(reduce(lambda x,y:x and y,[i % p != 0 for p in primes])):
          primes.append(i)
  print "Using map-reduce: ", time.time() - start, " seconds"
  ```

The results for `primeRange = 100000`:

```
Using map-reduce:  54.1150000095  seconds
Using C++-style:  4.62000012398  seconds
```

The 2nd case makes the code more compact, but the condition will be evaluated for the entire list and then reduced to `True` / `False`. Is there a way to avoid that?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You could use `all` with a generator expression:

```
if all(i % p != 0 for p in primes)
```

The generator expression will lazily evaluate one term at a time, and `all` will return early if it hits a value that doesn't satisfy the condition.

Answer (score 3):

yes, you should do two things.

First, if you want to avoid fully evaluating a list comprehension, don't use a list comprehension, use a generator expression:

```
... [i % p != 0 for p in primes] ...
```

should be

```
... (i % p != 0 for p in primes) ...
```

second, `reduce()` doesn't understand that `lambda x,y:x and y` can fail, and there's no way to teach it that.  But that doesn't matter, because python has a builtin function for exactly the fold over the conjunction monoid,  `all()`, so the `if` should be

```
if all(i % p != 0 for p in primes):
```

Answer (score 0):

Use generator,

```
def prime_iter(sz):
    '''
    Iterate through all the prime number in range [2,sz]
    '''
    bucket = [0]*sz
    for i in range(2,sz):
        if bucket[i]:
            continue
        for j in range(i+i,sz,i):
            bucket[j] = i
        yield i

# get all the primes from 2 to 100.
primes = list(prime_iter(100))
```